# Count number of instances of a class in multi-threading environment?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to count how many instances of a class generated during the run time of a process under multi-threading environment. The way how I do it is to increase a static counter in the constructor by looking at this post:
[How to Count Number of Instances of a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947571/how-to-count-number-of-instances-of-a-class)

So in multi-threading environment, here is how i define the class:

```
class Television {
      private static volatile int counter = 0;
      public Television(){
             counter ++;
      }
}
```

However, I am not sure whether there is a potential bug with the code above since I think **constructor in java does not imply synchronization** and `counter++` **is not atomic** so if two threads are creating instances simultaneously, is the code a bug somehow? but I am not quite sure yet.

Comment: Correct, there is a bug, because the read of counter and write to counter aren't atomically executed. Use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Use an atomic counter. tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Comment: And of course; the one interesting question is: why do you want to do that? What kind of problem do you intend to solve by knowing about the number of instances?

Comment: @GhostCat well, it's occasionally useful (very occasionally); my question would be why make it a static property of `Television`, as opposed to, say, an instance variable of a `TelevisionFactory`. What with mutable global state being pure evil.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks very much and it is very interesting. Could you explain how to use TelevisionFactory to count ?

Comment: @GuifanLi a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is just something that creates instances, e.g. it has a method which invokes `new Television()`. The variable can be a property of that class, rather than `Television`, so you can e.g. count the number of instances each factory has created.

Comment: @AndyTurner I got that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in this code (specifically, a race condition), because the read of counter and write to counter aren't atomically executed.

In other words, two threads can read the same value of `counter`, increment that value, and then write the same value back to the variable.

```
Thread 1    Thread 2
========    ========

Read 0
            Read 0
Increment
            Increment
Write 1
            Write 1
```

So the value would be 1, not 2, afterwards.

Use `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As `counter++` is NOT atomic, you can replace it with JDK's  `AtomicInteger` which is threadsafe.

You can `AtomicInteger`'s use `getAndIncrement()` method as shown below:

```
class Television {
      private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
      public Television(){
            counter.getAndIncrement();
      }
}
```

> An AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically
>   incremented counters, and cannot be used as a replacement for an
>   Integer.

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: No need to mark the AtomicInteger volatile.  Under the hood, it uses a volatile variable to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways here to bypass the underlying "++ on int" not being an atomic operation:

A) as others suggested, use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

B) introduce a common LOCK that all ctors can be using to sync on; like:

```
private final static Object LOCK = new Object();

public Television() {
  synchronized (LOCK) { 
    counter++; 
  }
```